# Analyzing cardinality of types in Java/OOP

Tags: java, oop, haskell, functional-programming, type-theory

In languages like Haskell, Purescript and Elm it can be powerful to think of types as sets, described [here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/appendix/types_as_sets.html). This tool helps you pick which data structure best fits for your problem. It also allows you to analyze how many impossible states there are.

Is it possible to take this idea and transfer it to procedural OOP languages, like Java, to analyze if impossible states are impossible? If so, how would that look?

EDIT: Cardinality of types gives us the number of possible values a type can represent. In FP, good practice is to model the types according to the data. By calculating cardinality we can then check if it is possible for our program to represent invalid data. If the cardinality of the data structure is higher than the amount of possible data/states it should hold, the data structure allows us to represent invalid data.

Contrast this to OOP. In OOP we do not model after types but rather after objects containing attributes and methods representing the real world. Is there a similar way in OOP we can analyze the amount of possible instances of an object to check if that object can contain invalid data? I suspect that objects might be too general for such analysis to be made.

Comment: As far as typing is concerned, a class *is* a (wrapper around a) product type, the constituent types being the types of the class's attributes. However, unless you make heavy use of enumerated types, cardinality won't help you much. Built-in types like `int` and `string` have infinite cardinality (effectively, anyway; if you are using this technique, knowing that the cardinality of `int` is ~4 billion won't be terribly useful.)

Answer (score 2):

You can translate those concepts to OOP languages like (I suppose) Java or C#. Some concepts have quite verbose translations, but I cover some of them [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/01/08/software-design-isomorphisms).

Product types are just your normal [Value Objects](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/ValueObject.html). Sum types are more tricky.

Consider the `Height` type from [the page linked to in the OP](https://guide.elm-lang.org/appendix/types_as_sets.html). You can [Church encode](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/05/22/church-encoding) it in C# like this:

```
public interface IHeight
{
    T Match<T>(Func<int, T> inches, Func<float, T> meters);
}
```

This also requires two classes that implement this interface.

It turns out that Church encoding of sum types is [equivalent to the Visitor design pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/25/visitor-as-a-sum-type), so you could also define the *Height* sum type as a Visitor:

```
public interface IHeight
{
    T Accept<T>(IHeightVisitor<T> visitor);
}
```

where `IHeightVisitor<T>` looks like this:

```
public interface IHeightVisitor<T>
{
    T VisitInches(int inches);

    T VisitMeters(float meters);
}
```

One of the implementations of `IHeight` ought to be this one:

```
public sealed class Inches : IHeight
{
    private readonly int inches;

    public Inches(int inches)
    {
        this.inches = inches;
    }

    public T Accept<T>(IHeightVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
        return visitor.VisitInches(inches);
    }
}
```

You'll also need another implementation, the `Meters` class, but I'll leave that as an exercise (hint: it looks a lot like `Inches`).

To be clear, something like the `IHeight` interface really ought to be an implementation detail. Here, however, I use it to 'show my work'. You should probably encapsulate the implementation so that no-one gets funny ideas about implementing that interface. Here's [an example of how you might do that with *Either*](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/06/11/church-encoded-either/#b001f5b4b4cb4b09a13d14063d4c542e).